# Is this a known distribution?

Tags: distributions, pareto-distribution, distribution-identification

For work, I plotted a set of shops by how many times they did business in the past week. The plot I got out looked something like this:

[image]

This looked obviously like a Pareto distribution. After all, that's the distribution of earthquakes and rich people. It would make sense in this sort of context. However, when plotting the log-log of this graph, instead of a straight line, I get this:

[image]

After further play with the data, I found that this curve could be straightened if I took a root of the log of the y value (in this case, the 3.9th root), and from that I derived a general formula for this and similar distributions I had seen:
$$
p=\exp({\sqrt[k]{-a\log{x}+b}})\quad   a,b,k>0
$$

I've done various searches and have looked through lists of named distributions, and haven't come across any distributions that resemble this one. Has anybody else seen this before?